# Dynamically created checkboxes with edittext and spinner children in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dynamically-generated

What I am trying to do is on selection of any item, from spinner, dynamically create a checkbox and when the checkbox is checked then I dynamically create edittext with a spinner. I got the layout but I am not sure what to do with edittext and selected spinner item (that are visible) and append it to a string.

> for eg: checkeditem:childspinner;checkitem:childspinner etc

Below is what I have tried but I am not able to get the text, spinner item and put it in the format. Any help would be appreciated.

```
checkBoxes = new CheckBox(Activity1.this);
checkBoxes.setText(materials[i]);

String matId = materialListIdMap.get(materials[i]);
checkBoxes.setId(Integer.parseInt(matId));
materialsUsedLayout.addView(checkBoxes);

EditText edittext=new EditText(Activity1.this);
edittext.setHint("Count");
allEds.add(edittext);
edittext.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Spinner uomSpinner = new Spinner(Activity1.this);
uomSpinner.setAdapter(unitofMeasurementAdapter);
uomSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

materialsUsedLayout.addView(edittext);
materialsUsedLayout.addView(uomSpinner);


checkBoxes.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(checkBoxes, edittext, uomSpinner));

View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final CheckBox button, final EditText      edittext, final Spinner uomSpinner)
{
    return new View.OnClickListener() 
    { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            if (button.isChecked()) {

                edittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                uomSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                uomSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
                    {           
                        Object obj = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);   
                        String newtext=edittext.getText().toString();
                        uomid=unitofMeasurementIdMap.get(obj);

                        System.out.println("*************id**"+newtext+"****" + button.getId()+"\\   \\"+uomid); 

                        StringBuffer edtBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                        edtBuffer.append(button.getId()+":"+uomid+";");
                    }
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }    

                });

                System.out.println("*************id******" + button.getId()+"\\   \\"+uomid); 
                System.out.println("and text***" + button.getText().toString()); 

                //System.out.println("buffer: "+edtBuffer);
            }
            else
            {
                edittext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                uomSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                System.out.println("no checking");
            }
        } 
    };
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. You should try and improve the question.

Comment: @Sundeep PFA image file attached where it would give you a much clear picture. http://imgur.com/FMEdY0L